# Spring Security 5 populating authorities based on JWT claims

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

As I see Spring Security OAuth2.x project was moved to Spring Security 5.2.x. I try to implement authorization and resource server in new way. Everythin is working correctly except one thing - `@PreAuthorize` annotation. When I try to use this with standard `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` I always get forbidden. What I see is that the `Principal` object which is type of `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt` is not able to resolve authorities and I have no idea why.

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken@44915f5f: Principal: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@2cfdbd3; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffffa64e: RemoteIpAddress: 172.19.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: SCOPE_read, SCOPE_write
```

And claims after casting it to `Jwt`

```
{user_name=user, scope=["read","write"], exp=2019-12-18T13:19:29Z, iat=2019-12-18T13:19:28Z, authorities=["ROLE_USER","READ_ONLY"], client_id=sampleClientId}
```

Security Server Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Bean
  public KeyPair keyPair() {
    ClassPathResource ksFile = new ClassPathResource("mytest.jks");
    KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(ksFile, "mypass".toCharArray());
    return keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("mytest");
  }

  @Bean
  public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    converter.setKeyPair(keyPair());
    return converter;
  }

  @Bean
  public JWKSet jwkSet() {
    RSAKey key = new Builder((RSAPublicKey) keyPair().getPublic()).build();
    return new JWKSet(key);
  }

  @Bean
  public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.jdbc(dataSource);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
        .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
  }

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
    security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
        .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
  }
}

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  public SecurityConfiguration(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers("/.well-known/jwks.json")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  }
}
```

Resource server configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ResuorceServerConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
    }
}
```

Maybe someone had similar issue?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

By default, the resource server populates the authorities based on the `"scope"` claim.
If the `Jwt` contains a claim with the name `"scope"` or `"scp"`, then Spring Security will use the value in that claim to construct the authorities by prefixing each value with `"SCOPE_"`.

In your example, one of the claims is `scope=["read","write"]`.
This means that the authority list will consist of `"SCOPE_read"` and `"SCOPE_write"`.

You can modify the default authority mapping behaviour by providing a custom authentication converter in your security configuration.

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt()
            .jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter());
```

Then in your implementation of `getJwtAuthenticationConverter`, you can configure how the `Jwt` maps to the list of authorities.

```java
Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> getJwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter converter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwt -> {
        // custom logic
    });
    return converter;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your SecurityConfig

```
.jwt()
.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
```

And the converter

```
private JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    // create a custom JWT converter to map the "roles" from the token as granted authorities
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
    jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
  }
```

Comment: This works, however, you would only have the roles and not the scopes (prefixed with SCOPE_). It can be extended of course to include both.