# How to enable OAuth on a specific endpoint using spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to familiarize myself with Spring Security, in particular migrating from Spring Security OAuth to Soring Security (as in the following example/guide https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide).

However, I am seeming to only get 403 Forbidden errors. I am accessing from Postman and am using my company's existing OAuth server. I am able to get a token from the auth server, so I know I have those credentials correct and I have verified what roles the OAuth user has.

I am using the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
```

This is the simple endpoint I am attempting to access:

```
@RestController
public class AppController
{
   @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

This is my application.yml file:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: <<company-website-here>>/uaa/oauth/token_keys
```

And this is my security configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/hello").hasRole("MY_ROLE")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why I seem to only get 403 errors. I have also tried adding @EnableWebSecurity to the security config class, but that didn't make a difference. Adding the auth server URL explicitly to the server and/or  manually creating a JwtDecoder didn't do the trick either; it appears the url is being automatically picked up from the yml file, based on its property name.

I am trying to move away from using the org.springframework.security.oauth.boot dependency and ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.

I had to add my own converter like so:

```
private static class JwtAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken>
    {
        private final Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;

        public JwtAuthenticationConverter()
        {
            this.jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = jwt -> jwt
                    .getClaimAsStringList("authorities")
                    .stream()
                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        @Override
        public final AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(@NonNull Jwt jwt)
        {
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(jwt);
            return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities, jwt.getClaimAsString("client_id"));
        }
    }
```

Then had to add this to the main security config:

```
.jwtAuthenticationConverter(new JwtAuthenticationConverter());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a couple of things happening.

1. As you're migrating to Spring Security 5, you may need to extract your authorities manually. Check this [post and it's correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379645/spring-security-5-populating-authorities-based-on-jwt-claims).
2. You are using **hasRole** function and this will append "ROLE_" before your authority/role. So if the role on your JWT token is not ROLE_JWT_ROLE you should use
   **hasTransaction**.

Comment: Looks like you were correct. I had to create my own Converter, I edited my own answer to reflect what I did